# Увеличение textarea по мере заполняемости - javascript

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

Как можно увеличить textarea по мере заполняемости с помощью javascript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Первый вариант:** 
P.S. *С помощью атрибута `contenteditable`*

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable></div>
```

**Второй вариант:**

```js
var textarea = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0];

textarea.addEventListener('keydown', resize);

function resize() {
  var el = this;
  setTimeout(function() {
    el.style.cssText = 'height:auto; padding:0';
    el.style.cssText = 'height:' + el.scrollHeight + 'px';
  }, 1);
}
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  resize: none;
}
```

```html
<textarea rows="1"></textarea>
```

Comment: Спасибо, а другого  пути нету?

Comment: @Denver чем этот путь не устраивает?

Comment: Если сделать что бы textarea была в одну строку, код будет не верно работать...

Comment: @Denver, добавил второй вариант

Comment: За другой вариант спасибо, Вертикально все верно, но по auto textarea стоит на две строчки, можно сделать на 1 строчку

Comment: Ага вижу, большое спасибо)

Comment: @Dmitry, много чем... Например, бордер клонируется(строчки тоже div): https://i.imgur.com/Fp3m7s0.png

Comment: У второго варианта есть недостаток. Можно вставить тонну текста через контекстное меню (мышью, без клавиатуры) и размер textarea не изменится. Ниже использользовали более подходящее событие `input`

Answer (score 2):

Один из вариантов...

```js
var tx = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea');
for (var i = 0; i < tx.length; i++) {
  tx[i].setAttribute('style', 'height:' + (tx[i].scrollHeight) + 'px;overflow-y:hidden;');
  tx[i].addEventListener("input", OnInput, false);
}

function OnInput() {
  this.style.height = 'auto';
  this.style.height = (this.scrollHeight) + 'px';
}
```

```css
.moka {
    font-family: Consolas;
    font-size: 16px;
    height: auto;
    border: 1px solid #e4dcdc;
    border-radius: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="moka">Привет
как
дела?</textarea><br>
<textarea class="moka">Все
в
норме</textarea>
```

[DEMO](https://codepen.io/pedro404/pen/rNwvobo) - для экспериментов на codepen.io
P.S. Код был немного модернизирован...

Answer (score 0):

Пример так, для коллекции.

```js
var textarea = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0];
/*
 Чтобы получить необходимы результат (автоматическая высота textarea)
 и исключить костыльный подход с setTimeout в теле инструкции обработчика
 resize, лучше подписать на событие input вместо keydown 
*/  
  textarea.addEventListener('input', resize);
        
  function resize(_e) {
var event = _e || event || window.event;
var getElement = event.target || event.srcElement; // var el = this;
/* для сброса фантомной высоты от бордера :) и если направление на уменьшение строк  */
    getElement.style.height = "auto"; 
/* вычисление и присвоение высоты */
    getElement.style.height = Math.max(getElement.scrollHeight, getElement.offsetHeight)+"px"
        }
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  resize: none;
  max-height: 100px;
 -off-padding:0
}/*-off- --- кастомный маркер для экранирование лишних CSS свойств*/
div {
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 1px solid;
    max-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable></div>
<textarea rows="1"></textarea>
```