# Как сделать увеличение высоты textarea при набирании определенного количества символов

Tags: javascript, html, css, input

У меня есть такая структура:

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="chat-messages"></div>
  <div class="chat-input">
    <form method="post">
      <textarea class="message-input"></textarea>
      <button class="send-button"></button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

send-button у меня находится над полем textarea в конце. Как сделать так, чтобы если вводить больше 50 символов, то происходил перенос строки и увеличение высоты textarea, как бы отбирая высоту у chat-messages, но эта отбираемая высота ограничена. Вот например у того же VK, Telegram и тд

Comment: Попробуй эти варианты: 
1) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/823925/%D0%A3%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-textarea-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-javascript

2) https://qna.habr.com/q/483255
https://jsfiddle.net/8m6vb2f0/1

Comment: вроде бы получилось сделать, но высота увеличивается вниз, а мне надо увеличивать высоту у textarea и уменьшать у chat-messages

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте написать минимальную высоту textarea, например (min-height: 100px)

Comment: так это просто начальная высота 100px. Попробовал

Comment: Ну, есть разница между высотой и минимальной высотой

Comment: так, у меня высота textarea 47px, мне надо такую же минимальную высоту поставить?

Comment: Да, попробуй...

Comment: ничего не изменилось. В общем попробовал один код, все работает, но почему то высота увеличивается вниз, она увеличивается у textarea, но уменьшается у chat-messages

Comment: const textarea = document.querySelector('.message-input');

textarea.addEventListener('input', autoResize, false);

function autoResize() {
    this.style.height = '48.5px';
    this.style.height = this.scrollHeight + 'px';
}